# Export one object with mongoexport, how to specify _id?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to export just one object with mongoexport, filtering by its ID.

I tried:

```
mongoexport -d "kb_development" -c "articles" -q "{'_id': '4e3ca3bc38c4f10adf000002'}"
```

and many variations, but it keeps saying

```
connected to: 127.0.0.1
exported 0 records
```

(and I'm sure there is such an object in the collection)

In mongo shell I would use ObjectId('4e3ca3bc38c4f10adf000002'), but it does not seem to work in the mongoexport query.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you should be able to use `ObjectId(...)` in the query argument to `mongoexport`:

```
mongoexport -d kb_development -c articles -q '{_id: ObjectId("4e3ca3bc38c4f10adf000002")}'
```

If that does not work, you can use the "strict mode" javascript notation of `ObjectId`s, [as documented here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Mongo+Extended+JSON):

```
mongoexport -d kb_development -c articles -q '{_id: {"$oid": "4e3ca3bc38c4f10adf000002"}}'
```

(Also note that strict mode JSON is the format produced by `mongoexport`)

Comment: Thanks dcrosta, I thought I had tried these ways, but I guess I messed up with " and 's ! Problem solved :)

Comment: So far best answer to deal with that problem is to use "$oid" instead of ObjectId()

Comment: I had to add double quotations to the query key (`_id`) as well

Answer (score 5):

for mongoexport version: r4.2.3

```
mongoexport -q '{"_id": {"$oid": "4e3ca3bc38c4f10adf000002"}}'
```

and for a nested field

```
mongoexport -q '{"_id": {"$oid": "4e3ca3bc38c4f10adf000002"}}' --fields parentField.childField
```

Comment: This is the only one in this thread that worked for me, thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

You have to specify the `_id` field by using the `ObjectId` type. In your question it was specified as a string.

CODE ::

```
mongoexport -h localhost -d my_database -c sample_collection -q '{key:ObjectId("50584580ff0f089602000155")}' -o my_output_file.json
```

> **NOTE** :: dont forgot quotes in query

Answer (score 3):

My MongoDB verion: 3.2.4. when I use `mongoexport` tool in mongo shell：

**NOT WORK:**

`-q '{"_id":ObjectId("5719cd12b1168b9d45136295")}'`

`-q '{_id: {"$oid": "5719cd12b1168b9d45136295"}}'`

**WORKs:**

`-q "{_id:ObjectId('5719cd12b1168b9d45136295')}"`


- Though in mongo [doc](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption--query) , it says that

> You must enclose the query in single quotes (e.g. ') to ensure that it
>   does not interact with your shell environment.

- But, single quote(') does not work! please use **double quote**(")!

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to add ObjectId or $oid as suggested by answers above. As has been mentioned by @Blacksad, just get your single and double quotes right.

```
mongoexport -d kb_development -c articles -q '{_id:"4e3ca3bc38c4f10adf000002"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

many of the answers provided here didn't work for me, the error was with my double quotes. Here is what worked for me:

```
mongoexport -h localhost -d database_name -c collection_name -q {_id:ObjectId('50584580ff0f089602066633')} -o output_file.json
```

remember to use single quote only for the `ObjectId` string.