# Can't get lists of sorted documents based on _id

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Not able to backup mongo documents with command below.

Error:

```
Failed: error parsing query as Extended JSON: invalid JSON input. Position: 15. Character: O
```

```
mongodump --db test-data --collection foo --out=dump --query '{"_id":{"$lt": ObjectId("5e25b7a5f4c9b92aaa8a4131")}}'
```

Comment: `ObjectId()` is not a valid JSON object

Comment: with version 4.2 Extended mode v2 is required...`ObjectId("5e25b7a5f4c9b92aaa8a4131")` needs to be replaced with `{“$oid”:”5e25b7a5f4c9b92aaa8a4131”}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export one object with mongoexport, how to specify \_id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155459/export-one-object-with-mongoexport-how-to-specify-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ObjectId` method returns a new ObjectId value which is not the ID value you passed in. The new ObjectId is invalid since is not part of JSON object.

Based on [this documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#bson.ObjectId), you can passed your ID value which is `5e25b7a5f4c9b92aaa8a4131` to the nested query `$oid` (object id).

**Query**

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$lt": {
      "$oid": "5e25b7a5f4c9b92aaa8a4131"  
    }
  }
}
```

**Final Solution**

```
mongodump --db test-data --collection foo --out=dump --query '{"_id":{"$lt":{"$oid": "5e25b7a5f4c9b92aaa8a4131"}}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use [MongoDB Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#bson.ObjectId) for this parse as json.

Your query becomes `{"_id" : {"$lt" : {"$oid" : "5e25b7a5f4c9b92aaa8a4131"}}}`